# Any idea where to find solidity problem sets?

Tags: solidity

To be clear, when I say 'problem sets', I'm not referring to exercises that require someone to identify a specific vulnerability, exploit, etc., or conjure a method of compromising a contract.

I'm referring to a classical code challenge / program set. For instance, an example problem set might contain a prompt that says: '*Write a python/C++ program to check whether the given number is even or not*'(won't bother to post any solution, you get the gist).

I'm wondering whether there's any equivalent for solidity (*or whether there* **can be** *an equivalent*). Given the fact solidity is used for a very constrained purpose (*comparative to other programming languages*), I wasn't sure whether such a concept could be possible.

However, if so, please feel free to reply with some suggestions! Also, I'd appreciate any suggestions for the best strategy one could use to curate an expansive problem set (*from scratch*). Of course, if a catalog of solidity-based coding tasks already exists out there, I'd **sincerely appreciate** a point in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can try codewars for Solidity (beta). You basically solve a challenge and basically you know you succeeded if your code can pass through their tests.

See: https://www.codewars.com/kata/solidity